# jQuery No image dimensions after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load, append

I have the following code, which loops to get all images in a table then appends them to `#featured` which is then appended to `#wrapper`. The problem is after everything is appended to `#wrapper`, images have no dimensions and for that reason non of them show. It's like having 0px width and height for images. How do i overcome this size issue.

```
var featured = '<div id="featured"></div>';
$('#imageTable tbody tr td img').each(function(){
    $(featured).append('<img src='+$(this).attr("src")+' />');
});
$(featured).appendTo('#wrapper');
```

I tried to solve this problem by doing

```
$(featured).load(function(){
    $(this).appendTo('#wrapper');
});
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Have the images loaded when you run this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that every time you say `$(featured)`, you're creating a brand new jQuery object; then you do something to it and throw it — and what you did to it — away. The result is that you end up appending an empty `<div id="featured">` to `#wrapper`: the images don't come out with no dimensions, they're just not there at all.

Create one jQuery object and keep using that one object:

```
var $featured = $('<div id="featured"></div>');
$('#imageTable tbody tr td img').each(function(){
    $featured.append('<img src='+$(this).attr("src")+' />');
});
$featured.appendTo('#wrapper');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PXVG2/

Doing `$(x).append(...)` over and over again will work provided that `x` is something that is already in the DOM; your `<div id="featured">` isn't such a thing. If you appended it to `#wrapper` first and `#wrapper` was in the DOM, then it would work okay if you used `#featured` instead of the HTML:

```
var featured = '<div id="featured"></div>';
$(featured).appendTo('#wrapper');
$('#imageTable tbody tr td img').each(function(){
    $('#featured').append('<img src='+$(this).attr("src")+' />');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vPyy6/

This latter approach is rather wasteful though, it creates a new jQuery object on each `.each` iteration. The first approach is much better.

Comment: This doesn't work. All images are loading but not displaying. If i add `style="width:300px;height:100px;"` to the image tag then all images show. I don't know how else we can solve this issue

Comment: @Pinkie: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ ? The behavior you're describing doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I should add that the table is not initially in DOM. I'm calling a php script that generates the table with it's image contents. The table is loaded directly to a jquery's UI dialog, then i'm doing the above code to get the content from the dialog box to #wrapper. It's probably working in your jsfiddle example because you initially have table and images in DOM.

Comment: @Pinkie: It doesn't matter when then table is added to the DOM as long as it is there before you try to find it. If the table isn't in the DOM then `$('#imageTable tbody tr td img')` won't find anything. You need to duplicate your problem where I can see it or I can't help.

Comment: I ended up getting the width height values with php. Your jsfiddle works. I'll accept this as an answer. Thanks